# Multi Column IF Statement or workflow solution

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, calculated-column-formula

Lets say 30 Columns and i need a calculated Column that says IF any of the 30 columns equals yes then it equals needs help, if no do do nothing. Is there anyway to do this. Or a workflow that does the following if any column contains yes the email creator the title of the line item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new list workflow using SharePoint Designer and then use If conditional check

Create a new variable and set value = 0

```
If currentitem:column1 equal  "Yes" 
    Set variable value = 1
If currentitem:column2 equals "Yes"
    Set variable value = 1
```

After completing this for all 30 columns. You can check

```
If variable equals 1
      Sent Email
```

This workflow should start automatically on ItemUpdate

Comment: I think this should work hopefully, it makes sense logically, unfortunately i cant test it because sharepoint designer wont let me publish the workflow.

Comment: Are you getting any error while publishing?

Comment: Errors were found when compiling the workflow. The workflow filers were saved but cannot be run. Unexpected error on service when associating the workflow

Comment: I would suggest you create a new workflow and just publish it and make sure its working. Then add one by one condition, keep testing as you add more activities.

Comment: I cannot publish any workflow no matter the simplicity but earlier this morning i was able to. It must be something IT related problem

Comment: You can check the logs for clue

Comment: I dont have access to the logs

Comment: I learned i can only publish workflows at certain times of the day. I was able to get it to work with one column but once i added more it wouldnt work on the other. Should it all be contained in 1 step in sharepoint designer or is each IF statement its own step? Right now it looks like this  Step: Step 1
 If Current Item:Ambient Operating Conditions equals Needs Attention
  Set Variable: WO to 1
  If Current Item:Accessory Review equals Needs Attention
   Set Variable: WO to 1
      If Variable: WO equals 1
       Email Current Item:Created By

Comment: All the conditions can go inside a single step. Make sure you are putting the next If condition outside the previous if and not inside.

Comment: I have that working now thanks for your help! Can you help with the second part of this. In the email body i have it doing a lookup on a column, but the interface is a repeating section. Is it possible that the lookup and return multiple values instead of sending a seperate email for each section repeated.